# I can't add the image path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I want to add the image code from a different query to another query, but it didn't work no matter what I did.

THESE ARE SEPARATE CODES WORKING PROPERLY

This is the working code I want to add:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Flex, Skeleton, Text } from '@pancakeswap/uikit'
import Balance from 'components/Balance'
import { useTranslation } from 'contexts/Localization'

interface TopFarmPoolProps {
  title: string
  percentage: number
  index: number
  visible: boolean
}

const StyledWrapper = styled(Flex)<{ index: number }>`
  position: relative;
`

const AbsoluteWrapper = styled(Flex)<{ visible: boolean; index: number; topOffset: string }>`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${({ topOffset }) => topOffset};
  opacity: ${({ visible }) => (visible ? 1 : 0)};
  margin-top: ${({ visible }) => (visible ? 0 : `50%`)};
  transition: opacity, margin-top, 0.4s ease-out;
  flex-direction: column;

  ${({ index, theme }) =>
    index > 0
      ? `
         ${theme.mediaQueries.sm} {
           height: 80px;
           top: 0;
           padding-left: 16px;
           border-left: 1px ${theme.colors.inputSecondary} solid;
         }
       `
      : `padding-right: 16px;`}
`

const TopFarmPool: React.FC<TopFarmPoolProps> = ({ title, percentage, index, visible }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  const topOffset = () => {
    if (index >= 0 && index < 2) {
      return '0px'
    }

    if (index >= 2 && index < 3) {
      return '80px'
    }

    return '160px'
  }

  return (
    <StyledWrapper index={index}>
      <AbsoluteWrapper index={index} visible={visible} topOffset={topOffset()}>
        {title ? (
          <Text bold mb="8px" fontSize="12px" color="secondary">
            {title}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <Skeleton width={80} height={12} mb="8px" />
        )}
        {percentage ? (
          <Balance lineHeight="1.1" fontSize="16px" bold unit="%" value={percentage} />
        ) : (
          <Skeleton width={60} height={16} />
        )}
        {percentage ? (
          <Text fontSize="16px" color="textSubtle">
            {t('APR')}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <Skeleton width={30} height={16} mt="4px" />
        )}
      </AbsoluteWrapper>
    </StyledWrapper>
  )
}

export default TopFarmPool
```

This is the other working code where I get the image path.

```
import React from 'react'
import { TokenPairImage, ImageProps } from '@pancakeswap/uikit'
import { mainnetTokens } from 'config/constants/tokens'

const CakeVaultTokenPairImage: React.FC<Omit<ImageProps, 'src'>> = (props) => {
  const primaryTokenSrc = `/images/tokens/${mainnetTokens.cake.address}.svg`

  return <TokenPairImage primarySrc={primaryTokenSrc} secondarySrc="/images/tokens/autorenew.svg" {...props} />
}

export default CakeVaultTokenPairImage
```

THIS IS THE CODE PAGE I WANTED TO ADD, BUT IT WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL.
I tried this way and I get an error.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Flex, Skeleton, Text } from '@pancakeswap/uikit'
import Balance from 'components/Balance'
import { useTranslation } from 'contexts/Localization'
import { TokenPairImage, ImageProps } from '@pancakeswap/uikit'
import { mainnetTokens } from 'config/constants/tokens'

interface TopFarmPoolProps {
  title: string
  percentage: number
  index: number
  visible: boolean
}

const StyledWrapper = styled(Flex)<{ index: number }>`
  position: relative;
`

const AbsoluteWrapper = styled(Flex)<{ visible: boolean; index: number; topOffset: string }>`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${({ topOffset }) => topOffset};
  opacity: ${({ visible }) => (visible ? 1 : 0)};
  margin-top: ${({ visible }) => (visible ? 0 : `50%`)};
  transition: opacity, margin-top, 0.4s ease-out;
  flex-direction: column;

  ${({ index, theme }) =>
    index > 0
      ? `
         ${theme.mediaQueries.sm} {
           height: 80px;
           top: 0;
           padding-left: 16px;
           border-left: 1px ${theme.colors.inputSecondary} solid;
         }
       `
      : `padding-right: 16px;`}
`

const TopFarmPool: React.FC<TopFarmPoolProps> = ({ title, percentage, index, visible }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  const topOffset = () => {
    if (index >= 0 && index < 2) {
      return '0px'
    }

    if (index >= 2 && index < 3) {
      return '80px'
    }

    return '160px'
  }

  return (
    <StyledWrapper index={index}>
      <AbsoluteWrapper index={index} visible={visible} topOffset={topOffset()}>


      // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO EXECUTE THE CODE. //
     <TokenPairImage primarySrc={primaryTokenSrc} secondarySrc="/images/tokens/autorenew.svg" {...props} />



        {title ? (
          <Text bold mb="8px" fontSize="12px" color="secondary">
            {title}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <Skeleton width={80} height={12} mb="8px" />
        )}
        {percentage ? (
          <Balance lineHeight="1.1" fontSize="16px" bold unit="%" value={percentage} />
        ) : (
          <Skeleton width={60} height={16} />
        )}
        {percentage ? (
          <Text fontSize="16px" color="textSubtle">
            {t('APR')}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <Skeleton width={30} height={16} mt="4px" />
        )}
      </AbsoluteWrapper>
    </StyledWrapper>
  )
}

export default TopFarmPool
```

Comment: What was the error?